# Regular expression to match text outside html tags and not between specific tag

Tags: php, html, regex

I trying to get a regular expression to match some words outside and between html tags (and not in tags themselves), but I also need to exclude them when they are between html heading tags (h1, h2, h3, etc...)

Here is what i tried: `/(\bword\b)(?=[^>]*(<|$))/i`

Live example:
https://regex101.com/r/rM8tU3/1

Excluding heading tags is the only element missing.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: php, just edited my question to add it.

Comment: could you provide the input here along with the expected output?

Comment: Regex is a bad idea to parse html

Comment: what i expect is to match words setted in the first parenthesis (they are matching in green on the live example) but i do not want to match them when they are between `<h1></h1>` (unlike as the live example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this pattern to skip/ fail everything between `<h1></h1>`
Updated per comment below

```
<h1>[^<>]*<\/h1>(*SKIP)(*F)|(\bsample|text\b)(?=[^>]*(?:<|$))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rM8tU3/5)

Comment: Thanks! but it match on `href="sample.html"` and it should not!