# Get a String not inside <b></b>

Tags: regex

Small regex question. I have string in the following format: 
`<b class="ui-tabel-cell-label>Titel</b>TheString that i want`
I am creating a mobile website using jquerymobile in which there is a tabel. I get this string when i try to get extract the cell value from this table. Unfortunatlly i didnt find a way to only get the Value of the cell instead i get the "th" element from the tabel aswell. So i thought maybe i can filter it out by using a regular expression. 
Could someone provide a regex which filters out the String part from <"b"><"/b"> and everything that is inside and inbetween so i only get the "The String what i want" part.

Comment: Doesn't make sense because in your title you've stated you want the string in between the `<b>`  & `</b>` .

Comment: The title says "Get string between <b> and </b>". In the question you ask for the string after the `</b>`. Which is it?

Comment: I am sorry fixed it :/

Comment: @TheWandererr: is ther somehing after your String? Like a new Tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match text outside html tags and not between specific tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647578/regular-expression-to-match-text-outside-html-tags-and-not-between-specific-tag)

Comment: @Smartis no there is nothing after that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1848654

Comment: Now, your question can be answered like this: *Is there a way* - there are a lot of ways, *using regex* - depends on what you can use: matching or replacing, but the regex will be *very* basic. Check [regexone.com](http://regexone.com) to learn the basics. Without knowing the environment you are working in, it is impossible to provide a clean and efficient solution.

Comment: You are right i will try to provide more info and a more detailed question

Comment: Updated my question maybe its a bit clearer now

Comment: @TheWandererr Does my answer not work? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your Question right, the suitable Regex String would be:

```
(?<=Titel<\/b>)(.*$)
```

You can check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/qY7iZ0/2) out.